# Chrome rendered font: OTS derived font—1 glyph

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, google-chrome-devtools, font-face

I'm using a font `Symbola`, but when I inspect an element with the following `font-family`

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Symbola;
    src: url(font/Symbola.eot);
    src: local("Symbola Regular"), local("Symbola"), url(font/Symbola.woff) format("woff"), url(font/Symbola.ttf) format("truetype"), url(font/Symbola.otf) format("opentype"), url(font/Symbola.svg#Symbola) format("svg");
```

}

```
font-family: Symbola, 'Times New Roman', serif;
```

Below at the computed styles section `Rendered Fonts` I get:

```
OTS derived font—1 glyph
```

[image: Chrome devTool style section]

Now I'm not sure what is going on here and what OTS means. Is `Symbola` used or not ?

Comment: Are Symbola and Times New Roman installed on your system? Is there a font named OTS derived font installed on your system? (And/or, are you using any @font-faces?) Which glyph is it?

Comment: I've updated the question. I have a Mac and I'm using chrome, I've never added fonts and there is no font named OTS

Comment: There is a bug in Chrome that causes Google fonts to be displayed as "OTS derived font" instead of the font family. See [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=514235).

Comment: @MrLister looks like that should be an answer so it can be flagged as correct

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans But it only answers one of the OP's questions, where the __OTS derived font__ comes from. The other, "Is Symbola used or not", I couldn't say!

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri if you are writing HTML for modern browsers, you can reduce your problem first by virtue of the fact that you don't need to do all this format juggling: just try to load local first, then try to load WOFF, and that's it. [No additional formats are required](http://caniuse.com/#search=WOFF), everything supports WOFF.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans But there are those who believe they'll also need to support Safari 5, the last Safari that runs on Windows. Oh, and IE8.